# Reclassify 2D stars array

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, raster, r-sf

With the [raster](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) package we can reclassify two dimensional spatial arrays as follows:

```r
set.seed(1)

library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

r <- raster::raster(matrix(sample(1:9, 100, replace = TRUE), 10, 10))

raster::plot(r)
```

[image]

```r
rcl_matrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(from = c(1,4,7), to = c(3,6,9), becomes = 1:3))

raster::plot(raster::reclassify(r, rcl = rcl_matrix, right = NA))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I struggle to do the same operation using the [stars](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stars/index.html) package. It is crucial that I do not have to specify the slice name as the array I am doing the operation for has always two spatial dimensions but the name can vary. In my actual applications there can be tens of different from-to classes. Specifying each one manually would not work. [A stars vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stars/vignettes/stars6.html) instructs to do the operation using `dplyr::case_when()` or `forcats::fct_recode()`. I only manage to do this a clumsy way:

```r
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

rcl_matrix <- as.matrix(data.frame(from = c(1,4,7), to = c(3,6,9), becomes = 1:3))
sr <- stars::st_as_stars(matrix(sample(1:9, 100, replace = TRUE), 10, 10))

plot(dplyr::mutate(sr, A1 = dplyr::case_when(A1 < 4 ~ 1, A1 < 7 ~ 2, A1 < 10 ~ 3)))

# OR:

sr$A1[sr$A1 <= rcl_matrix[1,2]] <- rcl_matrix[1,3]
sr$A1[sr$A1 <= rcl_matrix[2,2] & sr$A1 > rcl_matrix[1,2]] <- rcl_matrix[2,3]
sr$A1[sr$A1 <= rcl_matrix[3,2] & sr$A1 > rcl_matrix[1,2]] <- rcl_matrix[3,3]

plot(sr)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

How to do the reclassification for *stars* objects as elegantly/easily as for *raster* objects?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of doing it for numeric rasters. Note that you'll have to set the first break lower than in the `raster::reclassify` example.

```r
set.seed(1)
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

rcl <- data.frame(from = c(1,4,7), to = c(3,6,9), becomes = 1:3)
sr <- stars::st_as_stars(matrix(sample(1:9, 100, replace = TRUE), 10, 10))

plot(cut(sr, c(0, rcl$to), labels = rcl$becomes))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Different patterns in the outcomes stem from random sampling. The outcomes, in this case, are identical except that `raster::reclassify` returns numeric, while `stars::cut` returns factor:

```r
library(stars)
#> Loading required package: abind
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

dt <- matrix(rep(1:10, 10), 10, 10)
rcl <- data.frame(from = c(1,4,7), to = c(3,6,10), becomes = 1:3)

r <- raster::raster(dt)
sr <- stars::st_as_stars(dt)

r_rec <- raster::reclassify(r, rcl = rcl, right = NA)
sr_cut <- cut(sr, c(0, rcl$to), labels = rcl$becomes)

all.equal(as.matrix(r_rec), 
          matrix(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(sr_cut[[1]]))),nrow=nrow(sr_cut[[1]]))
)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Very interesting question... and very nice answer! Thank you very much for sharing. Cheers.